# Restricting access to certain areas of a flask view function by role?

Tags: python, flask, roles

I wrote this, which seems to work just fine:

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def admin():
    if not current_user.role == ROLE_ADMIN:
        flash('You do not have access to view this page.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
...the rest of my code...
```

While trying to simplify things since I don't want to add these 3 lines to every area I want only visible to admins, I tried to put it in a function like so:

```
def admin_only():
    if not current_user.role == ROLE_ADMIN:
        flash('You do not have access to view this page.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

and then put in my view function:

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def admin():
    admin_only()
...the rest of my code....
```

However this doesn't work as I expected. I get the flashed message, but it does not redirect like I thought it would.

So, two questions:

1. Why doesn't the returned redirect work?
2. Is there a better way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To actually answer your question. You should make the `admin_only` function a decorator and decorate the `admin` view method. The reason it does not redirect now is because you are not returning the redirect from the view.

```
def admin():
    ret = admin_only()
    if( not ret ):
        return ret
....
```

That should fix your current issue, but it is not ideal and the functionality you wish should be moved to a decorator.

I also recommend the following:

Take a look at [Flask-Principal](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/) it provides the ability to assign roles to users and then restrict access based on these roles to your views.

Along with Flask-Principal take a look at [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) as it provides many useful security related Flask extensions and just makes it easier to use.

Example use:

```
@roles_required( "admin" )
def website_control_panel():
    return "Only Admin's can see this."
```

Will *ONLY* allow users with the role `admin` attached to their account. Another use case is to allow a user to have one of many roles which can be specified with the `roles_accepted` and can be used as following:

```
@roles_accepted( "journalist", "editor" )
def edit_paper():
    return render_template( "paper_editor.html", ... )
```

Will only allow users that have at least one of the `journalist` or `editor` roles tied to their account.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough help! I'll check out those packages.

Comment: The negation in the first part of code should be removed, because it shows the restricted view anyway