# How i can give a access to a specific user with flask routes?

Tags: python, flask

I work with Flask and i want to specify the user how can get access with routes . in my case i want to give access only to the admin in this route :

````
@login_required
def compte():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(nom=form.nom.data,prenom=form.prenom.data,email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password,niveau=form.niveau.data,groupe=form.groupe.data,role='etudiant')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been created! You are now able to log in', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('compte'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.query.order_by(User.niveau.desc(),User.groupe).filter(User.role != 'admin').all()
    return render_template('compte.html',
                           form=form, users=users)```
````

Comment: create a decorator for admin users ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting access to certain areas of a flask view function by role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895839/restricting-access-to-certain-areas-of-a-flask-view-function-by-role)

Comment: Yess , Big thank's